# Is "Did they enjoy yourselves at the party?" correct?

Tags: grammar, reflexive-pronouns

I'd have gone for "themselves" instead of "yourselves", but my answer seems to be incorrect.

Could anyone explain to me why?

Comment: Can you add a source? Where are you getting this from?

Comment: Sorry, no source. It's just from a quiz program I have to use for an exam... I remember that the last year I bumped into something like this but I can't find that webpage any longer...

Comment: Hi Luca. This is the second question relating to an example from your quiz program, and the second in which the quiz has blatantly wrong English  (not a little bit wrong, or non-idiomatic, but very simple elementary school errors)   This program is worthless. You should not use it to revise for an exam.

Comment: Thank you... it's supposed to be correct and everything since it's official, but I think I put too much trust in it 

Comment: As now I'm sure it's actually wrong, I changed the subject of the question, which was misleading and I think that made my question get a downvote :(. Thank you lots, anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Did they enjoy yourselves .." is definitely wrong.

It should be either be "Did you enjoy yourselves.." OR "Did they enjoy themselves.."